# Web3 connection not open on send()

Tags: web3js

Since 2 days ago I now randomly get "connection not open on send()" while I never had that issue before. Does anyone know where its coming from?

```
  setTimeout(async () => {
  this.PROVIDER_URL = `wss://${process.env.CHAINSTACK_USER}:${process.env.CHAINSTACK_PASSWORD}@${process.env.CHAINSTACK_HOST}`
  this.web3 = new Web3(this.PROVIDER_URL);
  this.walletRepository = await getRepository(Wallet);
}, 6000);
```